# Use java code to enable portable wi-fi hotspot

Tags: android, wifi

currently I am building a very small native app for my android phone. I want to active the portable wi-fi hotspot when I click one button in the app. But I didn't know how to invoke Android API to active portable wi-fi hotspot. I know how to do it through the UI. Can anyone show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// code to enable portable wifi hotspot
public void EnableWifiHotspot(){
  try{
      WifiManager wifi_manager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          WifiConfiguration wifi_configuration = null;


          Method wifiHotspotEnabledMethod=wifi_manager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
          wifiHotspotEnabledMethod.invoke(wifi_manager, wifi_configuration, true);
   }
   catch (NoSuchMethodException e) 
      {

         e.printStackTrace();

      } 
      catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
      {

         e.printStackTrace();

      } 
      catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
      {

         e.printStackTrace();

      } 
      catch (InvocationTargetException e) 
      {

         e.printStackTrace();

      }

}

//code for disabling portable wifi hotspot
 public void DisableWifiHotspot(){
  try{
      WifiManager wifi_manager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          WifiConfiguration wifi_configuration = null;


          Method wifiHotspotEnabledMethod=wifi_manager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
          wifiHotspotEnabledMethod.invoke(wifi_manager, wifi_configuration, false);
   }
   catch (NoSuchMethodException e) 
      {

         e.printStackTrace();

      } 
      catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
      {

         e.printStackTrace();

      } 
      catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
      {

         e.printStackTrace();

      } 
      catch (InvocationTargetException e) 
      {

         e.printStackTrace();

      }

}
```